# Kobold 2dD - kkARCSupport.h file not found - how to manage that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, kobold2d

I want to use audio management from Kobold2D (ObjectAL)in my general (existing) Xcode (single view) project.

I use instructions from official:

> Copy libs/ObjectAL from this project into your project. You can simply
>   drag it into the "Groups & Files" section in xcode if you like (be
>   sure to select "Copy items into destination group's folder"). 
>   Alternatively, you can build ObjectAL as a static library (as it's
>   configured to do in the ObjectAL demo project).
>
> Add the following frameworks to your project: OpenAL.framework
>   AudioToolbox.framework AVFoundation.framework

But got this error: **kkARCSupport.h file not found.** Why?

Comment: If you're not developing a Kobold2D project, use the ObjectAL library from github. The one distributed with Kobold2D includes some fixes for ARC, which is why it's trying to import kkARCSupport.h.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D But I want to add this library to ARC project therefore I tried to use Kobolod2D